# Regex for javascript include query to filename

Tags: javascript, regex

There is jquery modal box called fancybox and its pretty cool i like it and intend to use it for my site, but the problem is that my flash video is actually video player and videos passed to it like query e.g. player.swf?videosource=video1.flv and this modal does not work it show contents of flash file as if you open in in text editor.
Inside there's code

```
ajaxLoader = null, imgPreloader = new Image(), imgRegExp = /\.(jpg|gif|png|bmp|jpeg)(.*)?$/i, swfRegExp = /[^\.]\.(swf)\s*$/i,
```

I believe i need to modify this regex "`/[^\.]\.(swf)\s*$/i"` expression to somehow include what i have after swf can someone help me do it i going crazy nothing i tried works.

Comment: Sorry, but what question are you asking here?

Comment: can you setup a demo somewhere so we can look?

Answer (score 1):

This regex should accept your player.swf?videosource=video1.flv query:

`/[^\.]\.(swf)(?:\?.+)?\s*$/i`

Comment: Its working thanks! I have to learn regex myself i keep walking around it almost every day nowdays.